# When create image from EC2 instance, is the default private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I would like to create an image from a EC2 instance that I already got the environment configured well. Before create it I want to make sure the image is only viewable by me and team members who have access to the same AWS account

I did not find place to specify whether the image created is private or public. My question is what is the default accessibility when I create image? Also where can I specify it.

Comment: Tested with a empty system, and the visibility shows private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AMI that you've created from an EC2 instance always has the `Owned by Me` permission and is private by default.

While the documentation doesn't say this explicitly, [here is one example:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html#buy-share-sell)

> After you create an AMI, **you can keep it private so that only you can use it**, or you can share it with a specified list of AWS accounts. **You can also make your custom AMI public** so that the community can use it.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation Adil